# Laurent series of $ \frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)} $ around $ z_0 = 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Attempted solution:

$ \frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z-2})$. So we study the fractions seperate.

$\frac{1}{z-2}= \frac{1}{1-(z-1)}= \sum_{k\geq0}(z-1)^k$ for $ |z-1| < 1$, and

$\frac{1}{z-2}= \frac{1}{z-1} \frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{z-1})}= \frac{1}{z-1} \sum_{k\geq 0} (\frac{1}{z-1})^k =\sum_{k\geq 0} (\frac{1}{z-1})^{k+1} = \sum_{k\geq 1} (\frac{1}{z-1})^{k} $ for $ | z -1 | > 1 $.

Q: Is this valid? $ f(z) = \frac{1}{z-2} = \begin{cases}\sum_{k\geq0}(z-1)^k \quad  |z-1| < 1 \\ \sum_{k\geq 1} (\frac{1}{z-1})^{k} \quad| z -1 | > 1 \end{cases}$

I'm quite stuck with $ \frac{1}{z-1} $. How do I expand this around 1...?

$\frac{1}{z-1} = -\frac{1}{1-(z-1)-1} = .... $

Comment: For starters, $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Klaus pointed out, your partial fraction decomposition is wrong. But putting that to one side here's how I would find the Laurent series:

Your question on how to expand $1/(z-1)$ about 1 is a little worrying, because $(z-1)^{-1}$ already is in the form you're looking for! In general you can make the question seem a bit more familiar by substituting something like $w=z-1$, and rewriting the function in terms of $w$:
$$w^{-1}(w+2)^{-1}$$
Note we now seek the Laurent series of this function about $w=0$. We have singularities at $w=0,-2$ so our Laurent series about $0$ is going to converge on $0<|w|<2$.

I don't need to do anything about the $w^{-1}$ term, it is already in the form I want (just as $1/(z-1)$ was before, but I hope its clearer why now). For the other term note:
$$(w+2)^{-1}=2^{-1}(1+\frac{w}{2})^{-1}=2^{-1}\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(\frac{w}{2})^n$$
for $|w|<2$ (which we have). So the Laurent series is:
$$\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n2^{-(n+1)}w^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge-1}(-1)^{n+1}2^{-(n+2)}w^n,\;|w|<2$$
You can now substitute back in $w=z-1$ for your final answer:
$$\sum_{n\ge-1}(-1)^{n+1}2^{-(n+2)}(z-1)^n,\;|z-1|<2$$